# Custom LAN Cable (within walls - new house) Problems

Tags: networking

I'm new to this forum but it looks like a wealth of information! I know enough to be dangerous - been online since 1990 (33.6kb days - remember those!, built my last 10 desktop computers) and I think I created a BIG problem in assuming it would be easy enough to install my own LAN wiring when building a new home for myself (I was the General Contractor on project).

I borrowed a (pretty fancy/expensive) LAN tester from my Internet Provider Tech, while he was at my house working on connectivity issues. From trial-and-error (there's a loooong story behind all this - I spoke to a couple of people in my process; that apparently didn't really know what they were talking about).

I have 10 LAN outlets/jacks ([https://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=105&cp_id=10513&cs_id=1051301&p_id=15673&seq=1&format=2][1]) that run through 2 switches ([1]: https://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=105&cp_id=10521&cs_id=1052104&p_id=10927&seq=1&format=2). I purchased an inexpensive LAN tester ($30) that seems to work just fine. It is showing a bad connection on a line that I just repaired/rewired!

Here's my wiring pattern for the cable end (at switch) (Doesn't appear  that I have a good-enough reputation, yet, to post more than 2 links)
From left-to-right

Orange stripe

Orange

Green stripe

Blue

Blue stripe

Green

Brown stripe

Brown

On the Wall Jack side (don't know if my link worked, so you can see a picture), I originally wired the jack side the same as cable-end (after lengthy conversation with Tech Support from Monoprice). This, of course, DID NOT work (my Internet Supplier Tech told me it had to be wired as shown on Jack, using "A"). After changing wiring sequence to that on the Jack, and testing the circuit with the "expensive" tester, all's Good! I did this with 2 circuits, as this was all the time I had to use the "expensive" tester. Here's the wiring sequence, from left-to-right that works on the Wall Jack:

Blue

Blue stripe

Green

Green stripe

Orange

Orange stripe

Brown

Brown stripe

The following question will show my inexperience: When cutting through the jacket (I used a knife), if I nick/cut-into the wire, will that cause problems?

In researching my problems, I found, via a How-To, that the amount of exposed wire (between the jacket and jack) doesn't matter on a wall jack - does it matter?

Thanks so much for taking time to help!

Comment: Welcome to the SU.   You might want to clean up your post to either get rid of the extraneous information - and there seems a lot of it relative to your question - or explain its relevance to the post.  (As asked it seems that only the last 3 paragraphs are relevant, and you could summarize the rest by saying "I have Cat5 cable running through my house)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback davidgo. Being new, but not new to Forums (I used to be an Admin on a very popular worldwide forum), I've seen where people do not provide enough "specifics" about their problem, so replies end up being about information they didn't provide in original post.

Comment: Rereading your post, There are a few things you may want to look towards (you can still get a cable which will pass traffic if you ignore them, but doing it the right way will make things easy and help debug).  First off, there are 2 cabling standards - TIA568A and B - it does not matter which you pick, as long as you stick with one - the A and B on the jacks represents th standards - so A-A or B-B.     You should also avoid Socket to RJ45 connections - Sockets for single strand in wall cabling, jacks for multi-core leads with RJ45 connectors.

Comment: 33.6k?  Get off my lawn, youngster!  I started with 1200! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you cut through the outer cable of Cat5 (or similar cable), provided you don't nick the inner cable it should have no consequence - unless you introduce sharp bends at that point which you would not otherwise have done.

If you expose the copper, then yes, it can cause issues - how bad the issues are depends on which cable was nicked and how deap.   Nicking the inner plastic is less of a concern, but theoretically could cause reduce the performance of the cable - but at the level you are talking you probably would not nice it.

There are 2 accepted ways of wiring cables - either will do fine.  In reality, on Cat5 you should be OK with any wiring provided that if you throw a cable tester across both ends it shows a 1:1 mapping of wires.

The amount of exposed wire from the wall to the jack definitely matters - the cable might work with more wire exposed, but it won't work as well.  The standards have very strict limits for the lengths of exposed cable - exceed these and interference means the cable will not perform as well as it shoul.  (For similar reasons thats why the middle pairs are split, and cat6 cable has more turns and better separation between pairs then cat5)

(The standard in the TIA568 standards, they are different for Cat5 and Cat6.  I can't remember the maximum length, but I think its about 1" from the end for Cat5 and less for Cat6)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the plastic outer jacket doesn't make a difference. It's not an electromagnetic shield in any way.  You could run the whole length without it if you want. What makes a difference is how much you untwist the twisted pairs.

Comment: Its not an electromagnetic shield, however it does ensure that the inner wires are kept in proximity to each other in such a way at to minimise RFI and ensure same-size cable lengths.

Comment: Making sure all 8 conductors are the same length could be important, but I'm pretty sure keeping one pair close to the next is not. It's all about differential signaling, not some slight shielding effect of keeping the pairs close to each other. You just need to keep both conductors of each pair close to each other so they're equally exposed to any noise source.

Comment: Thanks davidgo and Spiff. I tried to be very careful when stripping-off the outer jacket but "may" have nicked/exposed-copper when doing this. It sounds like this, and having too much wiring exposed between the jacket and wall jack could cause "performance" issues (which I don't want & will correct) but I'm not getting a "pass" reading on my LAN tester (several jumps/errors) readings.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not editing my original post, but I've found that people don't re-read a post for the edits, especially a long post like mine.

After rewiring both ends, I still get LAN Tester "errors" in the wiring sequence (it's simply a 1 through 8 light sequence). My info about nicked wires and exposed wiring were my way of asking if this would cause LAN Tester errors?

And, I haven't a clue about why I'm getting these errors.

Comment: If you are getting errors on a 1-8 light sequence type tester, then the problem is either wires in the wrong order (lights on in different positions/order on the tester) or wires which are broken or not punched down correctly - no light on one side.  These cable testers are great tools, but only check the very basics - if they fail it is a "hard" fail, rather then a fail "this cabling could work but might not work fast.  [ Although strictly speaking, depending on which wires are wrong the cable could still work ]

Comment: The Tester does light on in different positions/order and I just rewired this circuit. I rewired two other circuits, using same procedures, they checked out good and work (this was using the "expensive" tester). Upon fixing my connections, identical procedures as the other two, I'm getting Fail with my "limited" Tester.

Answer (score 0):

Rereading things, and in light of your comment -

I think you are trying to wire Socket to Jack, which is a no-no, but can technically work.  What I believe you have done though is used TIA856A on the socket side and TIA856B on the cable side.  To fix your problem you need to change the sockets to use TIA856B

IE Your socket should be wired
Blue
Blue/white
Orange
Orange/White
Green
Green/White
Brown
Brown/White

Comment: I had this same, lengthy conversation with Monoprice Tech Support before I originally wired this system (not know technical terms - TIA856A and TIA856B and their associated wiring patterns. I wired the socket with my sequence as described, which I got online for a Straight Through (versus Crossover) cable. The Tech told me to wire the jack with the same pattern, which no outlet worked. So - I wired the jack to the A pattern, got a perfect score with the expensive tester, and it works (connected to a 4K TV). Duplicated this process with another circuit with same results(connected to my desktop)

Comment: I'm afraid if I do your suggestion, I'll be back to where I started but maybe worse - I say this because all the other cables leading to this part of the circuit are wired as I stated for a straight through cable.

Comment: If you click on the link above, after/for Jacks, the color patterns (A & B) are not even close to the pattern that I used for the Sockets. This forum won't let me add a third link (to post a picture).

Comment: I want to understand your suggestion as I'm running out of extra wire to make changes. Your suggesting I wire socket to TIA856B (as you described) when I (assumed-through my original desc) that I wired the socket to TIA856? Why wouldn't I rewire the socket to TIA856A; and would this create a conflict with rest of system? Thanks!

Comment: You misunderstand me (and possibly I you) - Based on the wiring layout you provided in your question it seems to me you have cabled the sockets as TIA856A and the jacks as TIA856B, when both should be the same. Its usually cheaper to rewire sockets then jacks. I think your working cables are all working as crossover cables thanks to mdi/mdx negotiation in the switches/nics.

Comment: Thanks for bearing through this with me davidgo! The expensive tester indicates 1-1, 2-2, etc.. which I "assume" is straight through - maybe that just means everything is OK? The cabling for socket Does Not Match (or even close) the TIA856B, as shown on the Jack. Not a matter of "cost", a matter a having enough wire to keep making changes - Socket-end is at top of a closet with limited room to work.

Comment: Thanks davidgo! I know most forums frown (and for good reason) on posting email addresses.